# Pylance disable all warnings

Tags: python, pylance

I am currently running both Pylint and Pylance at the same time. I use Pylint for linting and use Pylance for all the other things it does (like code highlighting). This means I am getting some warnings twice, once from Pylint, once from Pylance.

I wish to disable all Pylance warnings. I have tried setting `Analysis: Type Checking Mode` to None and have looked through all other settings presented and still have a couple warnings showing up. For example `Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)` and `Pylance(reportMissingImports)` still show up.

I am using VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

Please see: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

I you want to disable everything (I assume all output from pylance are warnings),

you can add a `<project-root>/pyrightconfig.json` in your repo:

```
{
    "ignore": [
        "**"
    ]
}
```

Please read the link above for all the options and some samples at the end.

You can also add a commented line/lines in each specific file, This is nice when you explore and try to fix errors.

```
# <inside your python file that show this errors>
# pyright: reportUndefinedVariable=false, reportMissingImports=false, 
# pyright: reportOptionalSubscript=false, reportInvalidStringEscapeSequence=false
```